# didSelectRowAtIndexPath called only with long press on a tableView embedded in a container view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have a `UItableViewController` inside a containerView and when I touch in one of my cells, it doesn't call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. However, if I long press, this method is called normally.

I've used `storyboard` and my `delegate` and `datasource` are my `tableViewController`.

Here is my tableViewController code:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return nuberOfSections;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return nuberOfSections;  
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return heightForHeader;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.01f;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MWSideMenuTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"menuCell"];
    // cell settups
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    // Some action done
}
```

Comment: Are you using any gesture recognizers in any of your views?

Comment: Are you sure that you did not implement `didDESelect...` by accident instead of `didSelect...`?

Comment: I bumped with the same issue, Have you get to any conclusion on this?

Comment: I just ran into this issue and found that I had a tap gesture recognizer setup on my container view controller to dismiss keyboard. Check if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There could be three reasons

1. delegate is not set
2. Could be a typo in the didselectrowatindexpath
3. gesture recognizers might be used in container VC or containing VC

Answer (score 0):

same problem happened with me because I have added a tap gesture recogniser over it. `

> **If you have used any gesture try removing it**

` and check if it causing the problem.